# Group by does not appear to be working in union SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(subtotal) 
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(product_price * how_many_purchased) as subtotal 
  FROM $table_name 
  WHERE location_id ='$location' 
    AND created_at >= '$startDate' 
    AND created_at <= '$endDate'  
UNION ALL 
SELECT SUM(shipping_total) 
FROM $table_name 
WHERE location_id ='$location' 
  AND created_at >= '$startDate' 
  AND created_at <= '$endDate' 
GROUP BY order_id) as subtotal");
```

The select with group by does not appear to be grouping.

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Yes it is grouping. But then you sum everything up without groups. What result were you trying to get?

Comment: @JakubKania I was trying to sum the shipping_totals with a distinct order_id then add that into the other query where I have SUM(product_price * how_many_purchased)

Comment: Like without the outer query? It might be a good idea to show example of how you want your output to look like.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum the two values, you can do this in a single query.  The following should give the total value by `order_id`:

```
  SELECT SUM(shipping_total) + SUM(product_price * how_many_purchased) as subtotal
  FROM $table_name
  WHERE location_id ='$location' AND created_at >= '$startDate' AND created_at <= '$endDate'
  GROUP BY order_id;
```

The following for all the data:

```
  SELECT SUM(shipping_total) + SUM(product_price * how_many_purchased) as subtotal
  FROM $table_name
  WHERE location_id ='$location' AND created_at >= '$startDate' AND created_at <= '$endDate';
```

Comment: Just one of the queries needs to be grouped by the order_id that's why I did it with union